# Universal enveloping algebra of an ideal of a Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $I$ be an ideal of a Lie algebra $L$. By the PBW theorem, we can consider $U(I)$ as a subring of $U(L)$. Is it true that $U(I)$ is an ideal of the ring $U(L)$? If not, what kind of object it is?

Comment: Seems like a homework question

Comment: No, $U(I)$ always contains the identity.

Comment: @pancini This is not a hw problem... I was thinking about an easier proof of the invariance lemma and thought the proof will be easier if $U(I)$ is an ideal.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Then does this unital subring $U(I)$ have some special property distinguished from other subrings?

Comment: Because $I$ is a Lie subalgebra, $U(I)$ is a Hopf subalgebra. And the fact that $I$ is an ideal means in addition that $U(I)$ is invariant under the commutator action of $L$ on $U(L)$.